Convergence of $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}|\phi(x)|^{2}dx$
I'm interested in knowing if say I have $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\phi(x)|^2 dx$, does it converge (has finite value) if $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\phi(x)=0$? How would I prove this if it's true, and furthermore is it "iff" or "if" case? I want to guess that it's only true that if this integral converges then limit is zero but not other way around, but again I don't know how'd you prove this.
I suppose if it's true, we can start proving with showing if $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(x) dx$ converges and limit exists then $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}\phi(x)=0$, but again I am not sure how showing it for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\phi(x) dx$ $\implies$ showing for $\int_{-\infty}^\infty|\phi(x)|^2 dx$.
Can someone help a beginner?

Why don't you experiment with some examples yourself? Say with $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ and $\phi(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}$?

If i am correct in here, i believe those converge to 0 when you take limits? But what do I make of it?

Nvm i did what your suggestion and got: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\left|\frac{1}{1+|x|}\right|^2 dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+|x|)^2} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{0}\frac{1}{(1-x)^2} dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(1+x)^2} dx=1+1=2$ and for other $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left|\frac{1}{\sqrt{|x|}}\right|^{2} dx=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{|x|} dx=\int_{-\infty}^0\frac1{-x} dx+\int_0^\infty\frac1x dx=\infty$

A nice example is
$$\phi(x)=\sqrt{\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\frac{1}{1+(1+n^2)^2(x-n)^2}}.$$ This one does not converge to zero at infinity, but $|\phi|^2$ has finite integral. With this and with the example $\phi(x)=1/|x|^{1/2}$, you can see that none of the two conditions implies the other. If in addition you assume that the limits exist though, they must definitely be zero.

what's the motivation for this so specific $\phi$?

Your first choice of $\phi^2$ is a series of non-negative terms, the $n=0$ contribution being $1$ for all $x$. Surely this lower bound precludes a finite integral.

@J.G. it was a typo, corrected now, thank you. The motivation is that in order not to have decay to zero, I chose the function to look roughly as a sum of bumps that are centered around integer points. And each bump has height $1$ and width $1/\sqrt{1+n^2}$, so that the $L^2$ size of each bump is smaller and smaller as $|n|$ grows. So even if you have an infinite number of bumps, the sum of all contributions is finite.

An easier version would be $\phi(x)=\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z} \chi_{I_n}$, where $\chi_I$ is the characteristic function of $I$, and $I_n=[n-\frac{1}{2(1+n^2)},n+\frac{1}{2(1+n^2)}]$.

*the width of the bumps is $1/(1+n^2)$.
